# Hyperledger 1.0 - How does my peer know what Fabric CA instance to point to?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I followed the instructions here:

http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/ca-setup.html

I can get the Fabric CA up and running, but how does my peer call to it? I don't see any such settings in core.yml. Seems like it is listening on port 7054, but, after a peer is enrolled, does the peer have to communicate with Fabric CA to authenticate? Or does the peer communicate with it for other reasons and how?

Answer (score 1):

The peer doesn't communicate with the CA directly. An MSP needs to be configured for each peer and orderer to abstract the enrollment, certificate signing and verification mechanism. To make use of MSP service you have to create a $MY_PATH/mspconfig folder with admincerts, cacerts, signcerts and keystore as subdirectories. The certificates generated for various roles (peers, users, and admin) with the help of CA are to be kept in these directories for the peer to pick up. The mspconfig path in core.yaml for peer and orderer.yaml are to be set to the mspconfig folder created above. This can also be overridden using environment variables in the docker-compose files. Detailed setup information can be found here: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/hyperledger-fabric/latest/hyperledger-fabric.pdf (page 82)

Answer (score 0):

You should read this file(ex of network have 4 peer, 2 ca and 1 order). It will show you how CA get cert file of peer. https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node/blob/master/test/fixtures/docker-compose.yaml. sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0):

The Peer no longer enrols itself (like it did in 0.6) and currently does not talk to the Fabric CA at all.